# Laravel 4 - ErrorException Undefined variable

Tags: php

Trying to bind model to the form to call update function, but model is not found.

```
{{ Form::model($upload, array('url' => array('uploads/update', $upload->id), 'files' => true, 'method' => 'PATCH')) }}
```

Controller to get edit view

```
public function getEdit($id)
{
 $upload = $this->upload->find($id);

if (is_null($upload))
{
  return Redirect::to('uploads/alluploads');
}

 $this->layout->content = View::make('uploads.edit', compact('uploads'));
}
```

Controller to do the update

```
public function patchUpdate($id)
{
  $input = array_except(Input::all(), '_method');

  $v = Validator::make($input, Upload::$rules);

  if ($v->passes())
  {
    $upload = $this->upload->find($id);
    $upload->update($input);

    return Redirect::to('uploads/show', $id);
  }

  return Redirect::to('uploads/edit', $id)
   ->withInput()
   ->withErrors($v)
}
```

error i get

```
ErrorException
Undefined variable: upload (View: /www/authtest/app/views/uploads/edit.blade.php)
```

Comment: Where is your binding ? Did you bind the model in route ?

Comment: In routes I have Route::controller('uploads', 'UploadsController');

Comment: Then you have to pass the model from the controller when loading/showing the form, how do you show the form, code ?

Comment: I updated my question above, I get the selected id and pass that to the edit view

Comment: Its PHP error processed by Laravel error handler. Its nothing related to Laravel actually. Answer below is good one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not binding the model in the route then pass it from the controller when showing/loading the form for editing, for example:

```
public function getEdit($id)
{
    $upload = $this->upload->find($id);
    if (is_null($upload))
    {
        return Redirect::to('uploads/alluploads');
    }
    $this->layout->content = View::make('uploads.edit', compact('upload')); //<--
}
```

**Update:** You should use `compact('upload')` not `uploads` because the variable is `$upload`.

Comment: It's probably because of `if` condition, probably `$this->upload->find($id)` returns `null`.

Comment: In the url I can see that the correct id is passed. Does that mean the is not returning null ?

Comment: Yes, it's not null then, remove the `if` condition and check if works.

Comment: I removed the if condition as well, something else has to create this empty page, I can't seem to find it right now. Thanks for you help anyway.